# JQuery.Ajax POST request to Azure returning bad request

Tags: ajax, jquery, post, azure

I have mobile services configured on my Azure database and I am trying to send a POST request to update the data. The service keeps returning a bad request and I fear its because of the format of my JQuery.Ajax request. I have tried a number combinations but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. The schema of the request can be found here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj677200.aspx), any help would be appreciated.

```
function RegisterPatient(){

        var wsUrl = "https://vervemobile.azure-mobile.net/tables/ref_*****";
        var data = {"YearOfBirth":1970,"Sex":"M","ControlGroupMember":false,"OrganisationID":null,"Type":null}

        $.ajax({
            url:wsUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data:data,
            beforeSend: function (request)
            {
                request.setRequestHeader("X-ZUMO-APPLICATION", "******");
                request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
               alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));

            }
        });

    }
```

Thanks in Advance,
Bradley

Comment: Can you post the raw request/response?

Answer (score 2):

The request requires a json body to be sent, so you have to stringify your data.

```
    ... 
    $.ajax({
        url:wsUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        ...
```

Comment: Good Idea but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error - any other ideas? Thanks Again

Comment: Have you tried sending X-ZUMO-AUTH and X-ZUMO-MASTER headers as well.

Comment: I copied your code exactly, then changed the url and key to point to my own service and used the JSON.stringify(data) change that Musa suggested and it worked fine for me - the data was inserted into my Mobile Services table and a valid JSON response was returned with the 'id' property updated.